# give some ideas for giving sku values in magento site

Tags: sku

give some ideas for giving sku values in magento site

we are devoloping magento sites.

so we are in confusion about on what basis, we have to decide sku values.

we planning for products name or bar code or in product-name-brand-manufacturer.

how you are giving skus for your site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the criteria Google shopping wants for advertising. You need a MPN and an EAN to start advertising. If you have the choice i would use one of these. Maybe there is even some search traffic on some off these keywords.

Edit:
Here is a list off examples Google accepts:

https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160161?hl=en

Comment: hi,

thanks a lot for reply.

can you please give some examples....

Answer (score 0):

Best Way to give SKU name as Brand-Product-attribute.Attribute may be size or color.
For example If you want to give SKU for SONY LCD TV with 32 " size.
Then SKU will be SONY-LCD-32.

Hope this will help you.